# Is there a way to combine cells containing lists in excel so that the result maintains the lost order?

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have 2 cells in excel that contain lists and I want to concatenate the cells in such a way that I can join the list values to maintain the list order

***Sample Data***
[image: Sample Data]

Is there a way to concatenate cells in this way?

I've tried Concatenate and Textjoin functions but they both join the lists underneath each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BYROW` function:

```
C2: =BYROW(A2:B6,LAMBDA(arr,CONCAT(arr)))
```

[image]